# How to Create Shapfile through arcpy with a user input MGRS coordinate

Tags: python-2.7, geospatial

Using Python 2.7.10, is it possible to get user input of an MGRS coordinate and create a shapefile from that coordinate? I am finding ways to work with LAT/LON coordinates but not much from MGRS. I am sure someone has done this before, if you could please share your code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, sorry but I am just learning how to use python and its taking me a while to figure out what to search for.

If there is an easier way of doing this I would like to know for future though. 
create a GDB 
create a table in the GDB 
add field to the GDB with MGRS title
add cursor, adds a row to the table 
populate the MGRS coordinate received from user into MGRS column
Convert coordinate from MGRS to Lat/Lon, this creates a .shp while also adding the Lat/Lon to the attribute table for future if required.